# Physical stats of cable modems

Tags: hardware, cable, modem

I am interested in what physical stats are available for cable modems and what they say about that modem.

I can think of the that sound important to me:

- The ability to cope with strong or weak signals. Usually modem connections suffer when the signal is either too strong or too weak. There has to be an input range of the cable signal strength.
- The ability to filter the signal. Depending on the network there may be noise near the actual signal band so a good modem would be able to filter that. In addition the modem could work in poor network designs where there is a reflection of the signal overlapping with the signal.

I am currently experiencing some problems in my network and I think it may be due to strong variation in signal quality.

What are the physical core stats for a modem and how would they typically be visible in a datasheet?

Comment: Is this not the right forum for this?

Comment: I suggest to move your last two sentences out of the main question body, into a comment.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TR-069

Comment: Google for DOCSIS + your questions. Get sites/articles like: [FAQ: Acceptable cable modem signal levels.](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/5862)